# How to set span inside link to work collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So im using bootstrap collapse, but problem is that it open div only when i click on link but when i click on arrow(span) its not working. Any suggestion how can i fix this?

```
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#firms" href="#collapseOne1">
            Go to list <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
     </h4>
<div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
     aaaaa
    </div>
</div>
```

this is css for span:

```
.arrow-right{
    background: url('../img/sprite.png') no-repeat  -0px -2039px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 12px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding an `href="#collapseOne1"` to the span element?

Comment: i tried that...its not working

Comment: Can you also provide CSS of your span element too, might be collapsed 0px width or height

Comment: @DavidWilkinson that is my css for span

Comment: i dont think so that is because css of span becase even when i put <span> > </span> it also not working

Comment: I've created a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/DSGxz/1321 and it's working, Can you please check? Try to compare all your collapse code.